# CSS meter value

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a speed meter. Using simple HTML (PHP also OK).

I'm using this code.

```
<style>
meter[value="1"] ~ .meter-container { --turn: 1 }
meter[value="2"] ~ .meter-container { --turn: 2 }
meter[value="3"] ~ .meter-container { --turn: 3 }
meter[value="4"] ~ .meter-container { --turn: 4 }
meter[value="5"] ~ .meter-container { --turn: 5 }
</style>


<div>
<meter id="speed-meter" class="dashboard-meter" min="0"  max="100" value="1"></meter>
</div>
```

The meter value will change dynamically. Now the problem is, I can't type all the dynamic values manually.

Is there any way where,

meter[value="**This value will update automaticly according to the meter value**"] ~ .meter-container { --turn: 1 }

Comment: use Sass to generate the code